# Detecting programatically if an app is being desintalled ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uninstallation

I need to know when my app is being uninstalled from the device where is installed.

Exist any way to know that?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: no  Long answer: No, there is not

Comment: why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: Hi thanks for the short and long answers :p. I'm using Apsalar framework in order to know the actions that a user does within the app. Uninstall it is one of the actions we are interested to track.

Comment: It's necessary to downvote this question?

Comment: Here, you're back to zero. :) @borrden, can i borrow your answers on some occasions? :D

Comment: @rokjarc I release my comments under the MIT license.  I just needed at least 15 characters and that was what I came up with but I am glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: For devs looking for answer here. Try checking AppFlyer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. There's no API that will notify you of app uninstallation.

Indeed, in general unless your app is already running in the background, there's no way for your app to do anything unless the user starts the app from the springboard or in response to a notification.